# Where Do I Place Google Analytics Code Inside .ASPX Page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-analytics

I just signed up with google analytics and I am trying to find where to add the tracking code on my page.  I know how insert in basic html pages, I just have inherited a site that is a .aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can insert it anywhere and it would work, as long as it's not inside an ASP.NET control.  A good place to put it would be inside your Master Page file, if you have one (that way you just add the code once for your whole site).

Many front-end developers recommend putting your script at the bottom of the page, so that if it breaks, your page will still work.  I think the Google Analytics code should be pretty solid though, so you could place it in your HTML **head** section.

Answer (score 4):

Take the [Asynchronous Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) code (available in your Google Analystics pages) and place it just inside the `<head></head>` element of your code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
</head>
```

If you follow the link above, you'll see that you can split the script block, so that some of the code won't impact on the rendering of the page. However, you'll run the risk of losing some hits, if the user interacts with the page before the tracking code is loaded. So only do this if you have a specific need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

GA Code of Google Analytics code is the Global Site Tag (gtag.js) tracking code for any property. Copy and paste the GA code as the first item into the  of every webpage you want to track. If you already have a Global Site Tag on your page, simply add the config line from the snippet below to your existing Global Site Tag.

The Global Site Tag provides streamlined tagging across Google’s site measurement, conversion tracking, and remarketing products – giving you better control while making implementation easier. By using gtag.js, you will be able to benefit from the latest dynamic features and integrations as they become available.

Answer (score -1):

The tracking code is profile-specific, which is why you can only access it via the [Profile Settings](http://online-metrics.com/beginners-guide-to-google-analytics-profile-settings/) page for a specific profile. Please read [Where can I find my tracking code?](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032385?hl=en) for full instructions.